# angular 5 - http post with specific header

Tags: javascript, angular, http-headers

### **My headers are set in constructor as follow:**

```
this.headers = new Headers();
this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--boundary');
```

### I have collected data to post it out in **formData**

```
            .....
 let data = new FormData();
     data.append('file', file);
     data.append('fileName', file.name);
     data.append('fileSize', file.size.toString());
     data.append('fileType', file.type);
     data.append('fileLastMod', file.lastModifiedDate);
            .....
```

### **Here i am posting the data**

```
let url = 'http://api.********.com/gallery/'+ this.selectedCategory;
            this._http.post(url, data, {headers : this.headers})
                .toPromise()
                .catch(reason => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(reason));
                }).then(result => {
                console.log('From Promise:', result);
            });
```

### **But i get following error:**

[image]

### **API that i am approaching requires following:**

[image]

---

### So my question is how to set up these requirements like boundaries, content disposition an so on ? These are pretty new things to me.

Comment: change the header `headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');`

Comment: nothing changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sending formdata object in request then do not need to import content-type.

Angular HTTP method support multipart type, where as HttpClient also support multipart with default reportProgress feature which will notify uploading status

Solution- Use HTTP method, it will set boundaries on its own.